# Find perpendicular line and its intersection to a rectangle

Tags: c#, math

I have three points A, B & C and a rectangle as shown below. I want to know the x,y coordinate where a ray from A would intersect the rectangle given that it must also be perpendicular to a line from BC. I know how to find the point on BC that the ray would intercept but I can't seem to figure out how to extend from there to find the point it would intercept the rectangle. Illustration:

[image]

Here is the code I'm using to find the BC intercept.

```
double k = ((By - Cy) * (Ax - Cx) - (Bx - Cx) * (Ay - Cy)) / ((By - Cy) * (By - Cy) + (Bx - Cx) * (Bx - Cx));
double Dx = Ax - k * (By - Cy);
double Dy = Ay + k * (Bx - Cx);
```

How can I extend Dx and Dy out to intercept the rectangle?

Comment: This is homework. You should figure it out yourself.

Comment: anyway you don't give any information how the rectangle is expressed relative to the points. How do you someone may have a concrete solution about this problem? As far as I'm concerned it's just a matter of guessing the slope of A-B segment, then calculate the perpendicular = m, make a linear function y=mx+a where a is the deltaY from the rectangle lower side. In the end get the deltaX in the same way (from the right side) to make the rect function y=deltaX and find the intersection between the two

Comment: I should have added, the points are always inside the rectangle.

Comment: Off the top of my head, if point `D` is your rectangle intercept, if you have the point-angle (or point-slope) equation of your general line AD, sub in the X and Y values of the various sides of your rectangle.  Of the 4 answers, 2 will be in the same direction as your original angle (the other 2 will be the opposite direction).  Of the remaining two, take the line segment of shortest length.  That shortest line will be your intercept.  EDIT: You may have to check for the corner case scenario where your `AD` line is horizontal/vertical which actually simplifies the problem even more.

Comment: Actually, wouldn't the line intersect the rectangle in two places?

Comment: @HolgerBrandt It would if it's a line, but from the diagram, I suppose the intent is to consider the line `AD` as a ray passing through the line segment `BC`.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair well the topic says **line**

Comment: I edited the question to specify a ray, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @JustinBrown Depending on your algorithm, you might also need to consider the _"corner case"_ where the line exactly intercepts at a _corner_.  Please, hold your applause.

Comment: What information do you have? Do you only have A, B and C. Then this is impossible. you need to know the size of the rectangle and its location. If you have this, this should be fairly simple. Find the slope of the line and insert the max_x for the squre (x position of right vertical line). If the resulting Y value is outside the square, do the same, only for Y.

Answer (score 0):

First figure out how to find the intersection of two lines (being wary of the parallel case).

Then how to find the intersection or a ray with a line, if there is one.

Then how to find the intersection of a ray with a line *segment*, if there is one.

Then apply that to the ray from A and each of the four sides, and you're done.

Hint: you can represent a line or ray as a vector and a point. This way you can define the ray from A without worrying about the intersection with the line BC (which might not be between B and C).