# How do I calculate opposite of a vector, add some slack

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

[image]

How can i calulate a valid range (RED) for my object's (BLACK) traveling direction (GREEN). The green is a Vector2 where x and y range is -1 to 1.

What I'm trying to do here is to create rocket fuel burn effekt. So what i got is

- rocket speed (float)
- rocket direction (Vector2 x = [-1, 1], y = [-1, 1])

I may think that rocket speed does not matter as fuel burn effect (particle) is created on position with its own speed.

Comment: I guess you could move this into the math site? This problem involves a bit of algebra and trigonometry.

Comment: Rocket science ;) Are you trying to calculate the vector normal to the plane by given points?

Comment: [A post to get an idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650339/find-perpendicular-line-and-its-intersection-to-a-rectangle)

Comment: Gah, I just noticed your title doesn't match your picture. I guess you want the opposite vector so you can add it to the position of your rocket, but in that case your arrow heads should really point the other way. In case the other guy with an answer (now removed) reads this - sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cheap and cheerful trick with 2D vectors is to transpose the x and y, then flip the sign on one of them to get the perpendicular vector (pseudo code):

```
Vector2 perpendicular ( -original.y, original.x ) // Or original.y, -original.x
```

Then you could do something like:

```
direction + perpendicular * rand(-0.3 , 0.3)
```

**Update:** having realised the question asks for the opposite vector (too busy looking at the picture!) I figure I had better answer that too. Multiply 'direction' by -1 to get the opposite vector. So this:

```
perpendicular * rand(-0.3 , 0.3) - direction
```

should give you a random direction vector somewhere in your range (not normalised, but close enough for these purposes). Then you can multiply that result by a random number depending on how long you want the tail.

Comment: Wouldn't the perpendicular be ( original.y, -original.x ) or ( -original.y, original.x )

Answer (score 0):

If to expend upon OlduwanSteve's answer, you can make is such that it's somewhat physically accurate.

You want to create several vectors that will represent the expulsion (the red lines).
First define the number of vectors you want to represent the expulsion with - lets mark it n.

You want to get a set of n numbers which sum up to Vx. These numbers will be the x components of the expulsion vectors. You can do this like so (semi-pseudo code):

```
SumX = Vx;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Ax[i] = -rand(0..SumX); // Ax is the array of all expulsion vectors x components 
    SumX -= Ax[i]; 
}
```

Now you'll want to calculate Ay (the y components of the expulsion vectors). This is quite similar to calculating the, except that SumY = 0.

Here instead of splitting up SumY among n elements, you need to decide a maximal y component. Best way I can think of to select this is to define a maximal allowed angle for the expulsion vectors and define the maximal Vy using: maxVy = minVx*tan(maxAlpha).

Now you can get Ay using this (semi-pseudo code):

```
SumY = maxVy*2; // The actual range is (-maxVy, maxVy), but using (0, 2*maxVy) is simpler IMO
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Ay[i] = rand(0..SumY);
    SumY -= Ay[i];
}
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Ay[i] -= maxVy; // Translate the range back to (-maxVy, maxVy) from (0, 2*maxVy)
}
```

Now you have arrays of both the x and y components of the expulsion vectors. Iterate over both arrays and pair up elements to create the vectors (you don't have to iterate both arrays in the same order).

Notes:
• **I align the axes in my calculations such that X is parallel to the objects speed vector (the green line).**
• The calculation for maxVy does **NOT** guarantee that a vector of angle maxAlpha will be produced, it only guarantees that no vector of larger angle will be. 
• The lines Ay[i] = rand(0..SumY) and Ax[i] = -rand(0..SumX) may lead to vectors with components of size 0. This may lead to annoying scenarios, I'd recommend to handle away such cases (for instance "while rand returns zero, call it again").